# [hyperledger-fabric]: Channel and Consortium changes

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

If consortium X1 has organization R1 and R2 and I have created a channel C1 using this consortium. In the future, if I include R3 in X1 will R3 be a part of channel C1? If yes, then will it be able to see the previous transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a peer joins a channel, it reads
all of the blocks in the ledger sequentially, starting with the genesis block of the channel and continuing through the transaction blocks and any subsequent configuration blocks.

CLI command where peer joining the channel: peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block

If you notice my genesis block is provided at the time of peer joining the channel.
Reference: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/hyperledger-fabric/latest/hyperledger-fabric.pdf

Answer (score 0):

@NavneetSurana, welcome to the StackOverflow!!

consortium X1

- R1(org1)
- R2(org2)
- C1(channel1)

Now you want to onboard new organization called R3 to X1

Onboarding new organization to existing consortium **through** **channel** which means new org will join consortium by joining one of the channels present in the consortium. So new org peers can sync with other peers once join the channel and can see all previous transactions

Update channel:

check this https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/cl-add-an-organization-to-your-hyperledger-fabric-blockchain/